# storing byte array into a string variable in Go lang

Tags: arrays, string, sockets, go

I am using Go Lang for the first time.
I have a byte array which I want to send over a socket.
Currently, my socket data has string variables msg1,msg2, msg3.
I want to append my byte array to it. Below is the code snippet.

```
var arr1 [4]byte = [4]byte{11,22,33,44}

addr := msg1 + msg2 + msg3
socket.Send(addr, 0)
```

But when I try to do that I get an error.

```
addr := msg1 + msg2 + msg3 + string(arr1)

Error: cannot convert arr1 (type [4]byte) to type string
```

What should I do in this case?

Actual code

```
package main
import "fmt"

var arr1 [4]byte = [4]byte{11,22,33,44}
func main() {
    data := "msg1" + string(arr1[:])
  fmt.Printf("\n%s",data)
}
```

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go tour.golang.org to learn the basics of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A byte array cannot be converted to a string, but a byte slice can:

```
addr := msg1 + msg2 + msg3 + string(arr1[:])
```

Or declare the `arr1` as a byte slice:

```
var arr1 = []byte{11,22,33,44}
```

Comment: but i tried this, it still displays garbage data.

Comment: Your byte slice contains nonprintable characters.

Comment: I just added the actual code..can u plz check?

Comment: 11 and 22 are nonprintable characters. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: For eg : i was storing IP address "11.22.33.44" in my byte array, and trying to send it to a socket

Comment: Take a look at `net.IP`

Answer (score 0):

`byte` is not `string`, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII .

Guess u want this:

```golang
// var arr1 [4]byte = [4]byte{11, 22, 33, 44}
var arr1 [4]string = [4]string{"11", "22", "33", "44"}

func main() {
    data := "msg1" + arr1[0] + arr1[1] + arr1[2] + arr1[3]
    fmt.Printf("\n%s", data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `append()`, I have given you two ways. I don't know which of the way you really want. But I hope one of these ways will be helpful for you.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var arr [4]string = [4]string{"11", "22", "33", "44"}
var messages [3]string = [3]string{"msg1", "msg2", "msg3"}

func main() {
    // fmt.Println(arr[0:4])

    // One way
    appending1 := append(messages[0:1], arr[0])
    appending2 := append(messages[1:2], arr[1])
    appending3 := append(messages[2:], arr[2])
    fmt.Println(appending1)
    fmt.Println(appending2)
    fmt.Println(appending3)

    // Second way
    appending1 := append(messages[0:1], arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
    appending2 := append(messages[1:2], arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
    appending3 := append(messages[2:3], arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
    fmt.Println(appending1)
    fmt.Println(appending2)
    fmt.Println(appending3)
}
```

**One way result**

```
[11 msg1]
[22 msg2]
[33 msg3]
```

**Second way result**

```
[msg1 11 22 33 44]
[msg2 11 22 33 44]
[msg3 11 22 33 44]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

var byteArray [4]byte = [4]byte{11, 22, 33, 44}

func main() {
    msg1 := "HI"
    msg2 := "Hello"
    msg3 := "There"

    byteArrayToString := hex.EncodeToString(byteArray[:])
    fmt.Printf("\n%s", msg1+msg2+msg3+byteArrayToString)
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be way more informative with explanation of the provided code.